# C - Read in a large number from file

Tags: c, file, floating-point

I have a file with large numbers such as `-7.47004e-16` and I am trying to read it into a float array using

```
fscanf(rhs, "%f", &numbers[i]);"
```

this is in a while loop. But this does not work when we have a number as the one mentioned above.

Is this not working due to the number being so large? Or is this not working cause of the "e" in the number format?

Could you recommend some ways of doing this properly?

Thanks.

Note: Numbers is a float array and rhs is the file name. The file has one number per line and some numbers are in the same format as above and some numbers are much smaller such as, `-1.88493`.

Here is the code:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *rhs, *output;
    int niter, n, n1;
    // counters
    int i = 0, j = 0, k, m, p;

    rhs = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    // ab+ opens file for writting and creates the file if need be
    output = fopen(argv[2], "ab+");
    niter = atoi(argv[3]);

    // check if files open up or not, if not exit.
    if((rhs == NULL) || (output == NULL))
    {
        printf("Error Opening files.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read in N
    fscanf(rhs, "%d", &n);

    // initialize n1
    n1 = n + 1;

    // generate array to hold values from rhs file
    long double *numbers = (long double *)malloc(sizeof(long double) * ((n1)*(n1)));
    long double *y = (long double *)malloc(sizeof(long double) * ((n1)*(n1)));
    long double *f = (long double *)malloc(sizeof(long double) * ((n1)*(n1)));
    long double *yp = (long double *)malloc(sizeof(long double) * ((n1)*(n1)));

    // get numbers and store into array
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            fscanf(rhs, "%Lf", &numbers[i]);
            printf("i = %d, number = %Lf\n", i, numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    for(k = 0; k < niter; k++)
    {
        smooth(n, y, yp, f);
    }

    fclose(rhs);
    free(numbers);
    free(y);
    free(f);
    free(yp);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: There are more floating point types than `float`, like `double` or even `long double`.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the "e" in the format of the number?

Comment: Your fscanf line looks okay, and numbers with e in them can be read, so the error is probably somewhere else. Please show a minimal working program that still has the same problem.

Comment: Your code is using `long double` and `%Lf` formats; why was your question asking about `float` and `%f`?  At least your formats are accurate.  You're not checking whether your inputs are working; always check the return value from `fscanf()`.  Why `"ab+"` for the output file mode?  This code carries a lot of superfluous material; it is not an SSCCE.

Comment: Nobody commented on the fact that -7.47004e-16 is not a large number? It is in fact quite small. Was the intent to say that “-7.47004e-16” is a long numeral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### An SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *rhs = stdin;
    int i = 0;
    float numbers[2];

    if (fscanf(rhs, "%f", &numbers[i]) != 1)
        printf("Failed to convert anything\n");
    else
        printf("Got: %13.6e\n", numbers[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./flt
-7.47004e-16
Got: -7.470040e-16
$
```

Note that the code checks that the conversion is successful; you should always do that, and the correct test is as shown — did you get the correct number of successful conversions.  You can get a failure to convert without running into EOF, so testing against EOF is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

That particular number is not too big for an IEEE754 single-precision float so it should be fine.

I'd use `double` myself just for the added range and precision but that's personal preference.

One thing I'd like to clear up: you stated that `rhs` was a file *name.* I'm hoping it's really a file handle returned from `fopen`, otherwise that would entail a big problem :-)

In addition, I assume you meant the file has one number per *line,* rather than per file.

By way of example, see the following transcript, which shows an input file, C program using `fscanf` and the output, to see that this method should work fine:

```
pax> cat qq.in
    -7.47004e-16
    3.14159
    2.718281828459
    42

pax> cat qq.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main (void) {
        float f;
        FILE *fin = fopen ("qq.in", "r");
        while (fscanf (fin, "%f", &f) == 1)
            printf ("    %f %e\n", f, f);
        fclose (fin);
        return 0;
    }

pax> ./qq
    -0.000000 -7.470040e-16
    3.141590 3.141590e+00
    2.718282 2.718282e+00
    42.000000 4.200000e+01
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the size limit of float, since it could represent up to `2e−126`, about `1.18 *10e−38`. Perhaps you didn't indicate the precision of float when printing it out?

Try to print it out like this:

```
printf("%.30f\n", f);
```